# Why do i have error on printing the tf.Variable?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

When I write:

```
import tensorflow as tf

bool_variable = tf.Variable([False, False, False, True])
```

it saids that i have a error of:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: initialization error
```

And when I search it tells me to add:

```
tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()
```

But when I want to print the variable of:

```
print("As NumPy: ", my_variable.numpy())
```

It saids that i need to ***'ENABLE'*** the eager_execution

```
NotImplementedError: numpy() is only available when eager execution is enabled.
```

Comment: Do you actually HAVE an Nvidia GPU in your computer?  TensorFlow assumes there is one.  If not, then add `os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = "-1"` before you import tensorflow.

Comment: I did have Nvidia GPU in my computer, I can run other code, but not this one. Can you helo me?

Comment: Windows or Linux?

Comment: Your install of TF is broken. Follow the guide on the official website: [Install TensorFlow 2](https://www.tensorflow.org/install). Pay close attention to the requirements, especially CUDA and CUDNN versions.